# How to fix a loop on C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop, while-loop

I am working on a homework to where it asks the user to type in an abbreviation of states and when it gets the correct input it displays the full name of the state. I have the code below but for some reason even when I type the correct abbreviation, for example TN, I still get an Invalid Entry!. It has to be a simple mistake I am making in the while loop condition or I am missing something but I cannot seem to figure it out.. Help would be appreciated!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   string state;
   string KY, OH, IN, TN, WV;

   cout << "Question 1:" << endl;
   cout << "Enter state abbreviation (KY, OH, IN, TN, WV): ";
   cin >> state;

   while (state != KY && state != OH && state != IN && state != TN && state != WV) {
       cout << "Invalid Entry!";
       cout << "\nEnter state abbreviation (KY, OH, IN, TN, WV): ";
       cin >> state;
   }

   if (state == KY)
       cout << "Kentucky";
   if (state == OH)
       cout << "Ohio";
   if (state == IN)
       cout << "Indiana";
   if (state == TN)
       cout << "Tennessee";
   if (state == WV)
       cout << "West Virgnia";

   system("Pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The name of a string is irrelevant for its value. For example `TN` is the name for an empty string. You should probably initialize the name, e.g., using `std::string const TN(“TN”);` BTW, *always* check whether input was successful. You’d, e.g., use `if (std::cin >> state) { /* use state here */ } else { /* deal with input error */ }`

Comment: You defined the variable "WV", but you never assigned that variable any value (e.g. the string "WV").  SUGGESTIONS: `const string WV = "WV";`, or `string const WV("WV");`.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Yeah that makes sense. Sorry guys, that was a stupid mistake.. Thanks for the hep!!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify the contents of an an `std::string`, it will be initialized as an empty string, so your `OH`, `KY` (etc.) are all empty strings. Presumably you want something more like this:

```
string KY = "KY", OH = "OH", IN = "IN", TN = "TN", WV = "WV";
```

That should at least be a move in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the string variable KY, OH etc. these are different from strings "KY", "OH". You are comparing with the uninitialize string variables.

Comment: "You are comparing with the uninitialize string variables." they look pretty initialised to me.

Comment: @George looks like you are taking uninitialize as memory, I am talking about value here.

Comment: @Sanjeev Be precise with your terminology, that's an essential thing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ accepted and surely will consider it for my future response, thanks.